# how to know when to use CCdataType* varName vs. CCdataType *pVarName

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

my question is how do you know when to use the syntax `CCdataType* varName = ...`, vs. `CCdataType *pVarName = ...` I know that the second one is a pointer, but maybe I'm missing something... I don't understand the difference. is the first one a deference statement? do you use the pointer as in CCdataType *pVarName if the value you are referencing is out of the scope of the class that you are writing in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... I know that the second one is a pointer ...

Both are pointers. Just that the "*" is shifted left and right.

- `CCdataType* varName = ...` is conventionally considered more C++
  style.
- On the other hand `CCdataType *pVarName = ...` is more intuitive in
  the situations where you are declaring several pointer members, such
  as: `T *p1, *p2, *p3;`.

By the way, you can even write:

```
CCdataType*pVarName = ...
```

Here is the exact information to your question from [Bjarne's FAQ page](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace).

Comment: Worth mentioning: there is no difference. It's only a matter of style and preference respectively which coding guidelines you follow.